# How to display location info from a parser?

Tags: ocaml, camlp4

How can I display the location information when a `Stream.Error` occurs inside a parser? For example:

```ml
let p = parser
  | [< '1; '2 ?? "1 expected at line L, column C" >] -> ()
```

how to get the location in the stream? Is there a way to use `Stream.count` without having to count the newline characters manually?

Answer (score 0):

You have to build the position manually (represented with `Lexing.position` for example). I wouldn't touch the lexer/parser itself, though, but rather write a simple function that will translate a file offset (represented with `Stream.count`) into the (line, column) coordinate system.